# extend Widget's init method in odoo 13

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to extend the widget's init method to make a simple console.log when the page is loaded, but it doesn't work, what can be a correct way to do this?

```
odoo.define('lliege_pdt_main.pdt_maps', function (require) {
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');

    var pdt_maps = Widget.extend({
        init: function (parent) {
            console.log("test");
            this._super(parent);
        },
    });
    return pdt_maps;
});
```

Comment: You can check the [AbstractField](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/abstract_field.js#L95) widget, which extends `widget` and override the `init` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you do not want to inherit the widget in the classical sense. You want to **modify the parent itself**. This can be done with `include` instead of `extend`:

```js
var pdt_maps = Widget.include({
        init: function (parent) {
            console.log("test");
            this._super(parent);
        },
});
```

Don't forget to debug in assets debug (gorilla) mode. Here is the official documentation on patching a JS class like [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class).